# Como actualizar dos tablas en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

quisiera consultarles cómo puedo actualizar dos campos de dos tablas con SQL Server

El enunciado me pide: "Aumentar el precio de alquiler un 10.5% para los autos con una antigüedad menor a 2 años"
La tabla1 es "Alquileres" y la tabla2 "Automoviles". Ambas se conectan con la foreign key "id_automovil".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya, gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. En especial revisa el punto 3 de ¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?, y acompaña tú pregunta, con lo que has intentado.

Comment: Estoy con el mismo problema... pudiste encontrar la solucion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server soporta la ejecución de sentencias update sobre `joins`, con la sentencia `update`/`from`.

Básicamente, escribes un `from` como el de un `select`, con `joins` y `where`, para relacionar varias tablas, sobre las que puedes actualizar los datos en cualquiera, pero solo una de ellas, por ejemplo:

```
update Alquileres
   set Precio = Precio * 1.105
  from Alquileres
       inner join Vehiculos on Vehiculos.IDVehiculo = Alquileres.IDVehiculo
 where Vehiculos.Antiguedad < 2
```

Estoy asumiendo que existe un campo llamado antigüedad y que está expresado en años, ya te tocará a ti realizar las adaptaciones para que esto pueda aplicarse a tu modelo de datos real.